# Validar 2 ou mais emails em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação

Possuo um cadastro que faz validação de email no evento focusout no Input.
Essa validação funciona perfeitamente.
Agora surgiu a necessidade de validar vários emails dentro do mesmo Input, separando por ";" e como poderia tratar cada email de uma só vez?

```
$("#cobrancaEmail").focusout(function () {
    var valor = $("#cobrancaEmail").val();
    //valida se o email é válido
    if (validaEmailIE(valor)) {
        $("#cobrancaEmail").css({ "border-color": "blue", "padding": "1px" });
        $("#errocobrancaEmail").html("");
    } else {
        $("#cobrancaEmail").css({ "border-color": "red", "padding": "1px" });
        $("#errocobrancaEmail").html("E-mail inválido!");
    }
});


function validaEmailIE(email) {
    var regex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

Comment: E se você, ao invés de usar ID (e assim podendo somente passar 1 e-mail por página para o JQuery), utilizar class? Todos os e-mails que devem ser validados com a mesma class, poderiam ser passados para o JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro da função do evento do `focusout` você poderia adicionar um `split` e um `forEach`:

```
var valor = "fulano@email.com;teste@testando.com;maisum@email.com"
var contador = 0;

var arr = valor.split(';')

arr.forEach( function (element, index, array) {
    if (!validaEmailIE(element))
        contador++
})

if (contador > 0) {
    // algum email é inválido
} else {
    // todos os email são validos
}
```

Referências: [Split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)

Comment: Perfeito!  Obrigada